# Закомментировав подключение js файла в плагине, не нарушу ли я его работу?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такой весьма популярный плагин Subscribe To Comments Reloaded, в его файле stcr_utils.php есть вот этот код:

```
public function register_plugin_scripts() {
            $stcr_plugin_js  = ( is_ssl() ? str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', WP_PLUGIN_URL ) : WP_PLUGIN_URL ) . '/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/js/stcr-plugin.js';
            // Javascript
            wp_register_script('stcr-plugin-js', $stcr_plugin_js, array( 'jquery' ), null );
            // Enqueue Scripts
            //wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js');
              wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js','','','',true);
            // Styles
            //$stcr_plugin_css  = ( is_ssl() ? str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', WP_PLUGIN_URL ) : WP_PLUGIN_URL ) . '/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/css/stcr-plugin-style.css';
            //$stcr_font_awesome_css  = ( is_ssl() ? str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', WP_PLUGIN_URL ) : WP_PLUGIN_URL ) . '/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/css/font-awesome.min.css';
            //wp_register_style( 'stcr-plugin-style', $stcr_plugin_css );
            //wp_register_style( 'stcr-font-awesome', $stcr_font_awesome_css );
            // Enqueue the styles
            //wp_enqueue_style('stcr-plugin-style');
            //wp_enqueue_style('stcr-font-awesome');
        }
        /**
         * Hooking scripts for plugin pages.
         * @since 22-Sep-2015
         * @author reedyseth
         */
        public function hook_plugin_scripts() {
            // link the hooks
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',array( $this, 'register_plugin_scripts') );
        }
        /**
         * Enqueue `style for plugin pages
         * @since 22-Sep-2015
         * @author reedyseth
         */
        public function add_plugin_js_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js');
        }
        /**
         * Create a notice array with its settings and add it to the subscribe_reloaded_deferred_admin_notices
         * option.
         *
         * @since 14-Agu-2015
         * @author reedyseth
         *...
```

Я тут уже отключил стили, но у меня возник вопрос по поводу вот этой строки `wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js','','','',true);` Если её закомментировать, то скрипт в коде сайта не выводится.

Но вот ниже в файле имеется такой код

```
public function add_plugin_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js');
}
```

За что он отвечает? Если я выше закомментирую строчку, то не нарушится ли работа как-то, в частности, этого кода, назначение которого мне совершенно непонятно.

Да, в самом файле js код, который не нужен, он актуален только при активации определённой опции, которая у меня отключена. Вот я и хочу отключить его вывод.

Проясните, пожалуйста, это момент.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js');` подключает скрипт c handle `stcr-plugin-js`. К чему относится этот handle, ищите в вызове `wp_register_script()` с таким же handle. Если указанный там файл .js вам не нужен, можете комментировать эту строчку.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я думаю, вы можете оформить ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script('stcr-plugin-js');` подключает скрипт c handle `stcr-plugin-js`. К чему относится этот handle, ищите в вызове `wp_register_script()` с таким же handle. Если указанный там файл .js вам не нужен, можете комментировать эту строчку.